# Check on selectfield and input field

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to do the following:

I have 1 select field and 1 input field. When these are filled out the sum of both has to be written to the span .result. (Immediately! So not off focus from input field etc.)

I tried to use:

```
.on('click'
.on('change'
.on('blur'
```

and so on...

It only works on either input or selectfield but not on both at the same time.

To make this situation a bit more clear I added a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/go6g5b7h/)

Comment: Your fiddle seems to be working fine.

Comment: The problem was not that it wasn't working the problem was that it didn't update like i wanted it to do. Check the fiddle from Tushar. Thanks exactly what i wanted it to behave like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `input` and `select` events.

```
$('input, select').on('input select', function() {
```

1. `input` event will be fired when the value of the `input` is changed either by manually entering the value or by copy-paste.
2. `select` event will be fired on `<select>` when an `<option>` is selected.

[**Updated Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/go6g5b7h/3/)

```js
$('input, select').on('input select', function() {
    prijs_field = $('.prijs_field').val();
    btw_field = $('.btw_field').val();
    $('.result').html(prijs_field * btw_field);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="prijs_field">
<select class="btw_field">
    <option value="21">21%</option>
    <option value="6">6%</option>
    <option value="0">0%</option>
</select>
<span>the result is: </span><span class="result"></span>
```